# Distinguish between different users in struts2+hibernate

Tags: struts2, actioncontext

struts.xml

```
<package name="admin" extends="struts-default" namespace="/admin">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor class="interceptor.LoginInterceptor" name="loginInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>                 
        </interceptors>     

        <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>

        <global-results>  
            <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>                        
        </global-results>

        <action name="index">
           <result>/WEB-INF/admin/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        actions
        .
        .           

</package>

<package name="secure" extends="struts-default" namespace="/secure">
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor class="interceptor.LoginInterceptor" name="loginInterceptor"/>
            <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="loginInterceptor"/>
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
            </interceptor-stack>                 
        </interceptors>     

        <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>

        <global-results>  
            <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>                        
        </global-results>

        <action name="index">
           <result>/WEB-INF/admin/index.jsp</result>
        </action>

        <action class="actions.LoginAction" name="authenticateUser">
             <!-- generate dynamically for success-->
             <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
             <result name="error">/login.jsp</result>
       </action>

</package>
```

This is my iterceptor

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {        
        final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        Object user = session.getAttribute("user");
        if (user == null) {
            String loginAttempt = request.getParameter("loginAttempt");
            if(!StringUtils.isEmpty(loginAttempt)){
                return invocation.invoke();            
            }                            
            return "login";
        } else {            
            // Check for user role here
            // and redirect to action of specific namespace
            return invocation.invoke();
        } 
    }
```

Sorry my mistake I asked it wrongly.

There are two kinds of users in my application Admin and Customer.
I wants to distinguish between them and based on role redirect to specific namespace actions dynamically.

Currently there is only authentication functionality for admin.

I came up with this solution.

But I don't no how to map a request url to a action of specific namespece either 'secure' for Customer or 'admin' for Admin based on role.
Otherwise display global exception.

All JSPs for admin resides within admin folder and for customer inside customer folder in WEF-INF folder.

I also specified some comments which I still have to fill but don't know how to do this.
For cheking role I knows but for redirection don't know what to do.

I still had not implemented this. But I came with this idea.
Even what I think is possible or not.
If there is any better solution then you can tell me.

Comment: what's the problem you were facing with URL mapping, of course we can simplify this problem using spring security but it's for spring lovers :).

Comment: If you separate authentication (log in) and authorization (access to a resource) your issue will be pretty simple. Create a publicly accessible package (including logging in), a package for admin actions and a package for user actions, these will contain the authorization interceptor. This sounds like a simple case so a simple solution such as this should suffice. The book "Struts2 in action" demonstrates how to create such an interceptor.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please be more specific what do you want to achieve. What examples did you try?

Comment: Hello, I updated my post. Please see and provide any solution.

Comment: So just create different global-results like you did for `login` result and return them in your interceptor. BUT I suggest you to look at some security framework like spring-security.

Comment: @AleksandrM There is only one page for customer that I want to show and for that I can't take overhead of spring-security. And if I define different global-results that how can I call for that single page that will populate data into customer page.

Comment: @Rohit: What do you mean by populate data into page? Call some action.

Comment: Thanks to all for your reply. I implemented it just as @Quaternion told. And it worked very well.

Comment: @Rohit good work on finding a solution. Strange as it might be I really like closed struts2 questions if you have the time to document your own solution I'll upvote it. Just an FYI but there are a few recommending Spring security, this is overkill for this really simple case... but if you need heavier authentication then Spring-Security is much touted but do consider Apache Shiro should the need ever arise.